# Using QueryOver, how do I conditionally filter results based on a method argument?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

For a project I'm working on, I've recently been working with the `QueryOver` syntax in NHibernate, and I've hit a snag that I haven't found any texts on how to solve.

In the project I'm working on, I have a repository method to get a group of people assigned to a project.  The repository method looks like this (currently *non-functional* code)

```
public static IEnumerable<ProjectAssignment> GetProjectAssignments(int projectId, bool includeAlternates)
{
    using (ISession session = DataContext.GetSession())
    {
        List<ProjectAssignment> results = session
            .QueryOver<ProjectAssignment>()
            .Where(p => p.ProjectId == projectId)
                // Problem statement!
                .And(p => includeAlternates || !p.IsAlternate)
            .List().ToList();

        return results;
    }
}
```

My `ProjectAssignment` class is unimportant, as is its mapping, because the problem is obvious based on a question I asked earlier today: the `includeAlternates` boolean is not mapped to my `ProjectAssignment` class, nor should it be; it's an argument to the function.

What I'm trying to ask is:

```
Query all Project Assignments
    Where the project ID is the one I want
    And if alternate assignments are included, just include the assignment, 
        otherwise only include the assignment if it's not an alternate assignment
    And return that list from the query.
```

In order to do this, [I've been made aware of something called a Projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29103643/cannot-resolve-a-composite-property-using-queryover/), a new-ish concept to NHibernate.  However, having read some other questions, I'm very, very, *very* unclear on two key points, and trying to find official documentation hasn't helped, because it's written in a manner that I find completely opaque:

- What *is* a Projection, exactly?  One source said, 'it's like a SELECT statement in SQL'.  Another has likened it to a LINQ `.Select()` call, where it's actually just doing a transformation.  These are two *completely* different things as far as I'm aware, so one of those sources has got to be wrong.
- Back on the subject of my concrete coding problem - how to accomplish that pseudocode just above these questions - in what way can I *actually solve* my problem?

So, to my **questions:**

- What is a Projection in NHibernate, exactly?
- In what way can I achieve the conditional behavior as noted in my pseudocode block given above?

Comment: Select in LINQ and SQL are both projections.  The specifics of each vary a bit, but they are both inherently projecting data.  They are not *completely* different operations.

Comment: I don't agree. `SELECT * FROM Table` specifically *gets* all columns from table.  `someList.Select(i => i.ToUpper())` takes every item in `someList`, runs it against the given first-class function, adds that to an IEnumerable collection, and when that is done on every item in `someList` returns the IEnumerable collection that results from that.  That *is* completely different.

Comment: `select *` is the identity projection, in just the same way that `Select(x => x)` is an identity projection.  The operation, in either language, projects a sequence of data into another sequence of data through some specific transformation operation performed on each item in the sequence.  That is what a projection is, and they are two different implementations of a projection.  That the underlying implementation details of the data being projected is different doesn't change the fact that they are both projecting data.

Comment: Okay; that's my first question answered.  Now, in what way would I use that knowledge to do the selective filter based on my `includeAlternates` flag?  The code snippet I gave *will* (and, does) fail, because `includeAlternates` isn't mapped to anything, obviously.  Based on my previous experiences today with this, some other method is necessary to do the, `includeAlternates || !p.IsAlternate` filter.  The reason I'm asking this question, is I don't know enough about it, and the people around me don't either (they didn't know `QueryOver` was a thing prior to today, actually.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NHibernate will attempt to parse to SQL what you are including in your conditions and will be unable to as it is not part of your mapping or meaningful to the parser in that context, that's probably the error you're experiencing.
Projections are not a new concept to NHibernate at all but I don't see how they relate to your current situation.

Your code should read something more like below, where you include your condition to the QueryOver or not based on the boolean:

```
public static IEnumerable<ProjectAssignment> GetProjectAssignments(int projectId, bool includeAlternates)
{
    using (ISession session = DataContext.GetSession())
    {
        var query = session.QueryOver<ProjectAssignment>()
                       .Where(p => p.ProjectId == projectId);

        if (!includeAlternates) 
        {
            query.And(p => !p.IsAlternate);
        }

        List<ProjectAssignment> results = query.List().ToList();
        return results;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a much cleaner result than what I came up with before checking.  Pretty much, I had to create a `Restrictions.Or` between checking my flag against `true`, or `Projection.Property<ProjectAssignment>(p => p.IsAlternate)` against `true`, and saving that to an `ICriterion`.  I'm going with this.  I appreciate the awesome, and clean response, as well as the meaningful answer.

Comment: Good answer, this is one of the main reasons to use QueryOver-- you can easily generate different queries based on various parameters

Answer (score 1):

> What is a Projection, exactly? One source said, 'it's like a `SELECT` statement in SQL'. Another has likened it to a LINQ `.Select()` call, where it's actually just doing a transformation. These are two completely different things as far as I'm aware, so one of those sources has got to be wrong.

I think in the context of your other question, the comment was referring to the NHibernate `NHibernate.Criterion.Projections` class. This class' members can be used with QueryOver or Criteria queries to ultimately generate SQL from entities mapped with NHibernate.

Here's an example using the Criteria API and the `Projections.Property` method:

```
session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Person))
    .SetProjection(
        Projections.Property("FirstName"))
    .List<string>();
```

Since QueryOver is built on top of the Criteria API, you can still "drop into" the `Projections.*` methods when QueryOver doesn't support what you're trying to do for some reason. Your last question contained a good example of this; doing the following won't work with QueryOver:

```
session.QueryOver<Person>()
    .Select(p => p.LastName + ", " + p.FirstName)
        .List<string>();
```

However, this will:

```
session.QueryOver<Person>()
    .Select(Projections.SqlFunction(
        "concat",
        NHibernateUtil.String,
        Projections.Property<Person>(p => p.LastName),
        Projections.Constant(", "),
        Projections.Property<Person>(p => p.FirstName)))
    .List<string>();
```

Using projections tends to be more verbose but more powerful. You should be able to use expressions with the various `Projections` methods as well, eliminating the need for strings.

Fredy's answer takes care of the real problem, so I'll omit that part from my answer.